# Java: Enviar mensagem na network repetidamente em outro thread?

Tags: java, thread, socket

Ês o meu problema: Eu preciso que uma mensagem seja enviada por um socket repetidamente, para fazer isso, eu criei um outro Thread, para que a aplicação não ficasse travada, logo:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12739);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                s.writeUTF("Isso é um teste");
                s.flush();
            }
        } catch(IOException e){}
    }
});
```

O problema começa quando a mensagem "Isso é um teste" só aparece uma vez só, e depois não aparece mais, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro passo a se fazer é capturar a **Exception** que seu código pode estar gerando neste *loop* infinito que você fez nessa *Thread*.

Esse código dispara a toda velocidade essa mensagem pois não tem tempo de espera entre uma transmissão e outra. Logo, inicialmente imprima a *Exception* com um **e.printStackTrace()** , isso vai fazer com que você saiba o que está acontecendo.

Como é uma tarefa de atividade contínua, utilize um tempo de espera racional entre um disparo e outro com o **Thread.sleep(3000)** (neste exemplo o código espera três segundos quando lê esta linha).

Na sua expressão condicional procure utilizar uma variável que possa mudar de estado para encerrar a *Thread* em vez de uma expressão infinitamente verdadeira.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12739);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        while(true){// mude a expressão eterna por uma variável que possa retornar outro valor, para uma possível parada mais natural da Thread

            s.writeUTF("Isso é um teste");
            s.flush();
    Thread.sleep(3000L); // espera 3 segundos entre cada disparo
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();// sempre trate as Exceptions que seu programa possa disparar
    dos.close(); // sempre feche os fluxos em caso de erro, principalmente se os erros não fecham sua aplicação
}
}
```

});